# Prevent inserting to database If total value is equal to 0,

Tags: php, codeigniter

When adding scores for students, I would like those with a total score of 0 not to be inserted into the database at all.

Controller:

```
  public function entrymarks()
 {
 $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('', '');
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id', 'Subject', 'required|trim|xss_clean');

 if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
 $data = array(
 'exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id' => form_error('exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id'),
 );
 $array = array('status' => 0, 'error' => $data);
 echo json_encode($array);
 } else {

 $exam_group_student_id = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_id');

 $insert_array = array();
 $update_array = array();
 if (!empty($exam_group_student_id)) {
 foreach ($exam_group_student_id as $exam_group_student_key => $exam_group_student_value) {
 $attendance_post = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_attendance_' . $exam_group_student_value);
 if (isset($attendance_post)) {
 $attendance = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_attendance_' . $exam_group_student_value);
 } else {
 $attendance = "present";
 }


 $array = array(
 'exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id' => $this->input->post('exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id'),
 'exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id' => $exam_group_student_value,
 'attendence' => $attendance,
 'get_ca1' => $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca1_' . $exam_group_student_value),
 'get_ca2' => $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca2_' . $exam_group_student_value),
 'get_ca3' => $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca3_' . $exam_group_student_value),
 'get_ca4' => $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca4_' . $exam_group_student_value),
 'get_exam' => $this->input->post('exam_group_student_exam_' . $exam_group_student_value),
 'note' => $this->input->post('exam_group_student_note_' . $exam_group_student_value),
 
 );
 $insert_array[] = $array;
 }
 }

 if ( intval($array['get_ca1'] +$array['get_ca2']+$array['get_ca3']+$array['get_ca4']+$array['get_exam'] ) > 0 ) {
 $this->examgroupstudent_model->add_result($insert_array);
 }

 }
 $array = array('status' => '1', 'error' => '', 'message' => $this->lang->line('success_message'));
 echo json_encode($array);
 }
 }
```

I will like to first get the sum total of `get_ca1`+`get_ca2`+`get_ca3`+`get_ca4`+`get_exam`
 then if it is 0, don't insert.

Please how do I do this?

Comment: something like this :    `if ( intval($array['get_ca1'] +$array['get_ca2']+$array['get_ca3']+$array['get_ca4']+$array['get_exam'] ) >0 ) { $this->examgroupstudent_model->add_result($insert_array);}`

Comment: **REFORMAT your code first**. from where these comes? `$insert_array[] = $array;
 }
 }` ?? `}` ending

Comment: @jirarium, I get an error. The form is a popup so I cant  see what the error says

Comment: @AbdullaNilam, I have added the full code so you can see

Comment: @Esepebbles you already have them in the array right? `'total' = intval($array['get_ca1'] +$array['get_ca2']+$array['get_ca3']+$array['get_ca4']+$array['get_exam'],`

Comment: no, sorry, I just added that to play around with it? That was not in the original one

Comment: @Esepebbles after the `foreach` dump `$exam_group_student_value` value and post it. user `print_r($exam_group_student_value);die;`

Comment: I've done that, but I'm not getting a print. It just shows my popup form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can access the array value on the fly without any workaround, and you've placed the insert outside the `foreach`.

It would be best if you spent more time on these.

1. Code Indexing
2. Use proper IDE. Not like notepad.
3. Debug all and every line for errors.

---

Do like this.

> Since you're not using batch insert, you can do it one by one.

```
$cal1 = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca1_' . $exam_group_student_value);
$cal2 = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca1_' . $exam_group_student_value);
$cal3 = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca1_' . $exam_group_student_value);
$cal4 = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca1_' . $exam_group_student_value);
$exam = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca1_' . $exam_group_student_value);

$total = $cal1 + $cal2 + $cal3 + $cal4 + $exam;

$array = array(
    'exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id' => $this->input->post('exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id'),
    'exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id' => $exam_group_student_value,
    'attendence' => $attendance,
    'get_ca1' => $cal1,
    'get_ca2' => $cal2,
    'get_ca3' => $cal3,
    'get_ca4' => $cal4,
    'get_exam' => $exam,
    'note' => $this->input->post('exam_group_student_note_' . $exam_group_student_value)
);

if ($total > 0) {
    $this->examgroupstudent_model->add_result($array);
}
```

---

So final code will be

```
public function entrymarks()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('', '');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id', 'Subject', 'required|trim|xss_clean');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
        $data = array(
            'exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id' => form_error('exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id'),
        );
        $array = array('status' => 0, 'error' => $data);
        echo json_encode($array);
    } else {

        $exam_group_student_id = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_id');

        $insert_array = array();
        $update_array = array();
        if (!empty($exam_group_student_id)) {
            foreach ($exam_group_student_id as $exam_group_student_key => $exam_group_student_value) {
                $attendance_post = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_attendance_' . $exam_group_student_value);
                if (isset($attendance_post)) {
                    $attendance = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_attendance_' . $exam_group_student_value);
                } else {
                    $attendance = "present";
                }

                $cal1 = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca1_' . $exam_group_student_value);
                $cal2 = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca1_' . $exam_group_student_value);
                $cal3 = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca1_' . $exam_group_student_value);
                $cal4 = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca1_' . $exam_group_student_value);
                $exam = $this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca1_' . $exam_group_student_value);

                $total = $cal1 + $cal2 + $cal3 + $cal4 + $exam;

                $array = array(
                    'exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id' => $this->input->post('exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id'),
                    'exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id' => $exam_group_student_value,
                    'attendence' => $attendance,
                    'get_ca1' => $cal1,
                    'get_ca2' => $cal2,
                    'get_ca3' => $cal3,
                    'get_ca4' => $cal4,
                    'get_exam' => $exam,
                    'note' => $this->input->post('exam_group_student_note_' . $exam_group_student_value)
                );

                if ($total > 0) {
                    $this->examgroupstudent_model->add_result($array);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $array = array('status' => '1', 'error' => '', 'message' => $this->lang->line('success_message'));
    echo json_encode($array);
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. This resolved it, although I had to put in this ```$insert_array[] = $array;``` still

Comment: @Esepebbles wc. if you use my code you insert without `insert_array`

Comment: I did but my site became inaccessible.

Comment: go to the `add_result($array)` model and change access methods that may resolve this. any way happy to help

Comment: oh, that's true...completely forgot that part. will do so.

Comment: Hey, just noticed that even values greater than 0 are not inserted either

Comment: dump `$total` value and see. make sure `$this->input->post('exam_group_student_ca1_' . $exam_group_student_value);` can access values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246688/discussion-between-esepebbles-and-abdulla-nilam).